# java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\screenshot.png (Access is denied) error while trying to paste the screenshot to a system folder

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, filenotfoundexception

```
public class Automate1 { 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\chromedriver.exe"); 
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(); 
        driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies(); 
        driver.get("https://www.amazon.in"); 
        Select SC=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='searchDropdownBox']"))); 
        //Selecting an option from drop down by using Select class
        SC.selectByVisibleText("Books"); driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id=\"twotabsearchtextbox\"]")).sendKeys("The God Father"); 
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class=\"nav-input\"]")).click(); 
        JavascriptExecutor Scroll = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver); 
        //For Scrolling Functionality 
        Scroll.executeScript("scroll(0,800)"); 
        //Scrolling Up
        Scroll.executeScript("scroll(0,-200)"); 
        //Scrolling down 
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("The Godfather")).click(); 
        ArrayList Handles=new ArrayList(driver.getWindowHandles()); 
        driver.switchTo().window(Handles.get(1)); 
        Select Q=new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("quantity"))); 
        Q.selectByIndex(1); 
        driver.findElement(By.id("add-to-cart-button")).click(); 
        driver.close(); 
        driver.switchTo().window(Handles.get(0)); 
        TakesScreenshot scrShot =((TakesScreenshot)driver); 
        File SrcFile=scrShot.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE); 
        File DestFile=new File("c:\screenshot.png"); 
        FileUtils.copyFile(SrcFile, DestFile);
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\screenshot.png (Access is denied)
```

Comment: Error: Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\screenshot.png (Access is denied)

Comment: What is your question? Please do not just paste code with no context or question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, the root folder to a file system partition on a Windows base system is restricted to administrative access. This isn't a Java or Selenium problem as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new `File` you need to provide the *absolute path*, in terms of `root directory` (i.e. **`C:`**), `sub-directory` and the `filename`.

Effectively, you need to change the line as follows:

```
File DestFile=new File("C:\\some_sub_directory\\screenshot.png");
```

Comment: You don't need to do any of those things, and he is using absolute paths in the first place. He has `new File("c:\screenshot.png")`, which is an absolute path. But more correctly to your answer, `new File('screenshot.png')` is completely valid. Finally, the constructor for the `File(java.lang.String)` class constructor does not create any file.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
File DestFile=new File("c:\screenshot.png");
```

with

```
File DestFile=new File("c:/screenshot/screenshot.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File srcFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
try {
    FileUtils.copyFile(srcFile,
        new File("C:\\Users\\User\\OneDrive\\Pictures\\Screenshots\\Selenium\\img.png"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```